# Time Intervals In Python

Tags: python, date, types, fastapi, pydantic

I am making an app to schedule tasks (to actual people), and as part of it, I want them to be able to enter unavailability times in which they cannot be assigned tasks.

So I am looking for a notion of a time interval, i.e "Every week on Sunday between 1-2PM" or "Every month between the 4th at 3AM to the 9th at 6AM"

Something like a cron expression, except the fact it's not a single point in time but a continuous range in time.

And then I could tell if the task overlaps with this time frame and if so not assign it to that person.

While I can implement something like that myself, I would much rather use an existing builtin, or a pydantic type, because I want this unavailability interval to be passed by the API (I use FastAPI) instead of creating a million models for all the possible interval types allowed, including all the validation that comes with it.

Is something like that possible?

*Edit: This type is also useful for me for other places in the application. For example, the tasks themselves can reoccur every week on Sunday, and should be done between 8-9PM*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the dateutil package might solve your problem, particularly [rrule](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a similar application myself. I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but try the datetime library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). You could store the time interval as a tuple with the datetimeObj representing the start, the length being the length of the event, and the pattern being a timedelta object that stores the time between separate events. This could look like:

```
timeInterval = (datetimeObj, length, timedeltaObj)
```